# Jenkins Pipeline: build job with default paramter value if value not supplied

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline job that accepts 1 parameter with default value.
This job is building another job passing the parameter value.

Code of parent job:

```
node
{
    stage ('build job_1')
    {
        build job: 'job_1',
        parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'DROP_LOC', value: 'default_value']]
    }
}
```

Expected behaviour:

1. If parent job get DROP_LOC parameter value, it should use it to build job_1
2. If parent job has no DROP_LOC parameter value, it should use the default value to build job_1

Please help how to do that? What is the correct code?

Comment: So the parent job has DROP_LOC  parameter with default value and you want just pass a value if this parameter(default or specified) to another job? Or you want to pass it only if it will be non empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use DROP_LOC variable directly

```
stage ('build job_1')
{
    build job: 'job_1',
    parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'DROP_LOC', value:DROP_LOC]]
}
```

Comment: So if value:DROP_LOC is not supplied it will use the default?

Comment: @MosheRonen yes